# Can't upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

When I open the Software Updater the option to upgrade to 13.10 doesn't appear, what should I do?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades#Server_.2BAC8_Command_line_Upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This is the same command the updater uses, but you can see what it's doing.
But to have a sure and safe "upgrade", a complete reinstall would be more recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I run that and I get this error: 

"The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 96.0 M free 
space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 12.4 M of 
disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages 
of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'."

I checked /boot and effectively I don't have enough space :/, but the recommendations in the error message didn't help, how can I get more space there?

Comment: Please add the result of `ls /boot` to your question

Comment: I figured it out, I had some old kernels there, once I deleted one of them I had enough space and was able to upgrade without any issues. Thanks for your help, I'll mark your answer as the right one since it helped me figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `Software & Updates` from dash
2. Navigate to updates and set `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version` to `For any new version`

Note that you will not be able to upgrade till all the software on your computer is up to date

Comment: I already had this set up this way.